# Split at hyphens if NOT preceded by a whitespace or IS followed by a whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I want to split my string at each hyphen but only if it's not preceded by a whitespace. However, if it is followed by a whitespace, I wanna split it and have the hyphen removed. The same should happen if the hyphen is the last character of the string.

Example:

`myString = '- foo - -bar --baz -'`

Let's say I call

```
myString.split(regExImLookingFor).join(' ').split(' ').filter(word => word !== '')
```

I want it to return the following array:

```
[foo, -bar, --baz]
```

**Notice how all the orphaned hyphens disappeared**. There were 3 of them in `myString`: One at the start, one in the middle, and one in the end.

Comment: How about `-bar --word-with-hyphens`?

Comment: @SyedArsalanHussain This will only replace the first occurrence, right? I'm using it on my Node server and I don't have `replaceAll` available.

Comment: @gog This should actually separate word-with-hyphens so each word appears in the array individually.

Comment: So, [`myString.match(/-*[^\s-]+/g)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74220926/3832970) [**should work**](https://regex101.com/r/TL7CvJ/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew When I plug your regex into my code I get an array of 3 hyphens back

Comment: @FlorianWalther Please share the code. You need to use `String#match`. Node supports `String#match`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yea I just figured that out. The problem is that I need more fine-control over where exactly I split and I do this with additional split/joun calls chained together.

Comment: You do not need to split anything. Just match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249120/discussion-between-florian-walther-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated you would better not use `split`, but `match` for this. If however your requirement really is to have it work with the template code you provided, then the `regExImLookingFor` can be as in below snippet.

```js
let myString = '- foo - -bar --baz aaa-bbb -';
let result = myString.split(/(?<![-,\/\s])-+(?![-,\/\s])|(?:[-,\/\s]+(?:[,\/\s]|$))/)
                     .join(' ').split(' ').filter(word => word !== '');
console.log(result);
```

With `match` it becomes easier though:

```js
let myString = '- foo - -bar --baz aaa-bbb -';
let result = myString.match(/(?:(?<![^,\/\s])-+)?[^-,\/\s]+/g);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The reason I use split is that I split it at more places (`/` and `,`) and this way it's just more readable than having one huge regex that handles all of this.

Comment: Your solution works with one exception: It doesn't split `hyphenated-word`. What would I need to add to split this up into two separate words?

Comment: Oh ok, I updated the regex to have that effect.

Comment: Almost. When it splits a hyphenated word, I need that middle hyphen to disappear

Comment: I have trouble understanding the logic. So what if we have `aaa------bbb`? Then don't you want any hyphen to be retained? Could you edit your question and clarify more what the logic is for keeping/rejecting hyphens? Could you also clarify whether you really need this to work with `split` (according to your template code) or whether `match` based solutions are OK for you as well (as other answers are suggesting)?

Comment: I have updated the answer assuming the multiple hyphens linking words should split a word and throw away the hyphens, like `aaa------bbb`  should become `['aaa', 'bbb']`. Let me know if any other logic needs to be implemented.

Comment: `match` is fine for me too, thank you! Yes, the multiple hyphens in the middle should disappear. I am implementing a search functionality and I want a leading hyphen that doesn't connect two words to mean "exclude this word" just like in Google search. As far as I can tell, your new regex works perfectly  I'll try it out a bit more and then accept your answer.

Comment: What do I need to add to also split at slashes `/` and commas `,`?

Comment: I would need more information: do they always disappear, or are some of them kept in the output? What if they are combined with hyphens in some way, like `a,-b`, `a, -b` or `a-,b`... Do they act more like spaces or hyphens, or some hybrid?

Comment: The commas and slashes should always disappear. In your example above, the first two should evaluate to `['a', '-b']` and the second one to `['a', 'b']`. I think it behaves like this right now except for the comma splitting.

Comment: OK, it seems like comma and slash act exactly like spaces. So would you get the desired result if you first replace all of them with spaces? (I'm not saying that is how you should do it, but just as a verification I understand how these characters play out).

Comment: Yes, that should be correct. I used split/join originally and did `split(',').join(' ').split('/').join(' ')`

Comment: Alright. I updated the two snippets in my answer accordingly.

Comment: It works from what I can tell  Thank you for all your efforts.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `match` using this regex:

```bash
-*[\w+#]+(?:-[\w+#]+)*
```

**Breakdown:**

- `-*[\w+#]+`: This pattern matches 0 or more hyphens followed by 1+ word or `+` or `#` characters.
- `(?:-[\w+#]+)*`: matches 0 or more repeats of hyphenated words

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4qXqsv/3)

**Code:**

```js
var s = 'hyphenated-word - foo - -bar --baz - C++ C# '

var arr = s.match(/-*[\w+#]+(?:-[\w+#]+)*/g);

console.log(arr);

//=> ["hyphenated-word", "foo", "-bar", "--baz", "C++", "C#"]
```

Comment: Thank you. Where would I add additional characters that I want to allow as part of a word? I need to add `+` and `#` because I'm preparing a search for programming courses and it needs to accept e.g. `C++` and `C#`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But there are special characters that I *want* to split at. Right now those are `/` and `,` but I might add more in the future. How can I add them to the regex above so they are treated like whitespaces?

Comment: @FlorianWalther: Just use `/-*[\w+#]+/g` or see updated answer

Comment: @anubhava Thank you, it works! Now I'm unsure which answer I should accept as correct. Yours works the best for my use case, but I was asking about join + split in my original question. What do you think I should do?

Comment: There is still a problem, unfortunately. When I type in `hyphenated-word` I want to get `['hyphenated', ''word]` but right now I'm getting `['hyphenated', ''-word]`. How can I get rid of the leading `-` but keep it when there is no other word before?

Comment: If there are two leading `--` before a word (e.g. `--testing`) I don't really care if the result is `--testing` or `-testing`, i.e. if we remove all but one hyphen.

Comment: But you still want to get `-bar` when there is a space before `-bar`?

Comment: Yes. Basically, I want to allow users to exclude search terms (like on Google) by adding a minus in front of it. But I want to split hyphenated words and get rid of that hyphen in the middle.

Comment: @anubhava Now the output is completely wrong. Maybe it's better to use split/join combinations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249117/discussion-between-anubhava-and-florian-walther).

Comment: can you please clarify, what's wrong? Output just has additional `hyphenated-word` now

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
myString.match(/-*[^\s-]+/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TL7CvJ/1).

*Details*:

- `-*` - zero or more hyphens
- `[^\s-]+` - one or more chars other than whitespace and hyphens.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
myString = '- foo - -bar --baz -'
console.log(myString.match(/-*[^\s-]+/g))
```

Comment: Thank you. What can I add to this regex so that it also splits at `/` and `,` as if they were whitespace? The reason I use this split/join approach is that I treat different special characters differently in my real code.

Comment: @FlorianWalther Then use `/-*[^\s\/,-]+/g`, add more chars as you see fit into the character class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use split with a pattern and specify the different scenario's:

```
   *-(?: +|$)| +(?=-)|\b-\b
```

**Explanation**

- `*-(?: +|$)` Match optional spaces, `-` and 1+ spaces or the end of the string
- `|` Or
- `+(?=-)` Match 1+ spaces asserting `-` to the right
- `|` Or
- `\b-\b` A hyphen between word boundaries

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQoXkb/1)

```js
const regex = / *-(?: +|$)| +(?=-)|\b-\b/;
[
  "- foo - -bar --baz -",
  "hyphenated-word"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.split(regex).filter(Boolean)));
```